# Convert a string in a float with Riemann in clojure

Tags: clojure, type-conversion, riemann

I am processing streams in Riemann and all the fields are strings. However I'd like to perform some numeric comparisons on some fields. Therefore I tried to convert them in float.

Let's say my stream is like that :

```
#riemann.codec.Event{:host "myHost", :service nil, :state nil, :description "my description", :pred_score "0.156"}
```

I've tried to modify the `riemann.conf` file with something like this :

```
(streams
 (with :new_field (read-string :pred_score))
 prn)
```

However I got some error and I feel like this is not the correct way to do this. I have recently read some stuffs making me think that I should use `smap` or `adjust` but I'm not sure.

I am absolutely not familiar with clojure by the way. (In fact I discovered it with riemann).

Have you got any idea on how to tackle the problem ?

Thanks in advance,

Robin.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the riemann part, but in plain clojure you could use either Java interop or [the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo).  Using Java interop, you'd do:

```
> (def x {:host "myHost", :service nil, :state nil, :description "my description", :pred_score "0.156"} )
> (Double/parseDouble (:pred_score x))
0.156
```

The 'tupelo.parse' namespace wraps this inside a normal clojure function, and adds the ability to specify a default value to return in the event of a malformed value (instead of throwing an exception):

```
> (require '[tupelo.parse :as parse])
> (parse/parse-double (:pred_score x))
0.156
> (parse/parse-double "123.4x6" :default 0)
0
```

Comment: You should [add a disclaimer that you are the author of the library](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298734/is-it-acceptable-to-promote-my-own-library-as-part-of-a-real-answer#comment217878_298743).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, however I still get an error :
`clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Here is my syntax :

`(streams
(if (>  (Double/parseDouble (:pred_score event))  0.5)  prn )
)`
Did I made something wrong with the clojure syntax, or is it an error due to some Riemann config that i messed up ?

Comment: Could it be something as simple as `event` being undefined (i.e. `nil`)?  You need to paste the whole code for us to see a problem like that.  Try just typing `(println "event=" event)`